# how many times specific days occur in a date range in ruby?

Tags: ruby

i have two dates i.e.

```
start date = "2013-06-01" 
end date = "2013-12-01"
```

I am trying to achieve how many times mondays and tuesdays occur within this date range?

```
specific_days = 2 #monday and tuesday
total days = end_date - start_date 
total_weeks = total_days/7
total_specific_days = total_weeks * specific_days
```

but this doesnt assures the mondays and tuesdays occurences

Comment: can u edit the qsn with the piece of code you tried

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429156/how-do-i-get-all-sundays-between-two-dates-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very similar to [How do I get all Sundays between two dates in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429156/how-do-i-get-all-sundays-between-two-dates-in-ruby).

Get all days between this dates and select the days, which weekday number is `1` or `2`. Sunday is the first weekday (`= 0`).

```
require 'date'

start_date = DateTime.parse('2013-06-01')
end_date = DateTime.parse('2013-12-01')

result = (start_date..end_date).to_a.select { |d| [1,2].include?(d.wday) }

result.count
```

The result is `52` times.

Comment: Nice answer buddy worked totally... didnt know about the already asked question....

Answer (score 4):

Use [wday method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-wday) of Date class that returns the day of week (0-6, Sunday is zero), so Mon is 1 and Tue is 2.

```
require 'date'
dates = [*Date.new(2014,1,1)..Date.new(2014,10,1)]
p dates.count{|d| (d.wday == 1) || (d.wday == 2) }
```

Result:

```
#=> 78
```

**Updated**

To compare `array` and `range` sets:

```
require 'date'
require 'benchmark'

d1 = [*Date.new(2013,2,11)..Date.new(2013,12,25)]
d2 = Date.new(2013,2,11)..Date.new(2013,12,25)

n = 10000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('array') { n.times do d1.count{|d| (d.wday == 1) || (d.wday == 2) }; end }
  x.report('range') { n.times do d2.count{|d| (d.wday == 1) || (d.wday == 2) }; end }
end
```

Result:

```
         user     system      total        real
array  0.405000   0.000000   0.405000 (  0.419041)
range  1.498000   0.000000   1.498000 (  1.505150)
```

Comment: There is a specific need to build an array instead of send `count` directly to the range?

Comment: I think `dates = Date.new(2014,1,1)..Date.new(2014,10,1)` would also work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more verbose using [`Date#monday?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-monday-3F), [`Date#tuesday?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-tuesday-3F) and  [`Enumerable#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```
require 'date'
start_date = Date.parse("2013-06-01")
end_date = Date.parse("2013-12-01")

(start_date..end_date).count { |d| d.monday? || d.tuesday? }
#=> 78
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=> (Date.parse(start_date)..Date.parse(end_date)).count{|d| d.wday == 1 || d.wday == 2 }
# 52
```