# Is there any way to find dates for all wednesday in next 6 months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have use case where if user selects date like 21th May 2014 (i.e Wednesday). Then, i need to find the date for all the Wednesday for next 6 months.

Is there any easier way or api for it in rails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429156/how-do-i-get-all-sundays-between-two-dates-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
2.1.1 :041 > date = Date.today + 1.day
Wed, 21 May 2014
2.1.1 :042 > array = []
[]
2.1.1 :043 > 24.times { array.push(date); date += 7.days; }
24
2.1.1 :044 > array
[
    [ 0] Wed, 21 May 2014,
    [ 1] Wed, 28 May 2014,
    [ 2] Wed, 04 Jun 2014,
    [ 3] Wed, 11 Jun 2014,
    [ 4] Wed, 18 Jun 2014,
    [ 5] Wed, 25 Jun 2014,
    [ 6] Wed, 02 Jul 2014,
    [ 7] Wed, 09 Jul 2014,
    [ 8] Wed, 16 Jul 2014,
    [ 9] Wed, 23 Jul 2014,
    [10] Wed, 30 Jul 2014,
    [11] Wed, 06 Aug 2014,
    [12] Wed, 13 Aug 2014,
    [13] Wed, 20 Aug 2014,
    [14] Wed, 27 Aug 2014,
    [15] Wed, 03 Sep 2014,
    [16] Wed, 10 Sep 2014,
    [17] Wed, 17 Sep 2014,
    [18] Wed, 24 Sep 2014,
    [19] Wed, 01 Oct 2014,
    [20] Wed, 08 Oct 2014,
    [21] Wed, 15 Oct 2014,
    [22] Wed, 22 Oct 2014,
    [23] Wed, 29 Oct 2014
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

today = Date.today
six_months = today.next_month(6)
(today..six_months).select {|date| date.wday == today.wday}
```

or if you actually just want all Wednesdays:

```
(today..six_months).select &:wednesday?
```